# Force Gradle To Resolve Snapshot Dependencies From Different Repo

Tags: gradle

In my build.gradle for a Java project, I have a list of Maven repositories I am pointing to for dependency resolution, as follows:

> repositories {
>
> ```
> maven {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>     url "https://artifactory.myco.com/artifactory/maven-us-east-1-local"      
>
> }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> maven {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>     url "https://artifactory.myco.com/artifactory/maven_snapshots-us-east-1-local"
>
> }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> mavenCentral()                                                                                                                                                                                           }
> ```

It looks like the snapshots repo above barfs during resolution when gradle tries to see if a non-snapshot dependency lives there, as it goes through and contacts each repo in order. In artifactory it has been configured with a policy and it sends back a 409 conflict when it gets asked if it has a non-snapshot dependency. This is what I get:

> ./gradlew build
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration > 'com.myco.project:pgs_common:compile'.
>     Could not resolve mydep:mydep:1.0.9.
>     Required by:
>       com.myco.project:pgs_common:1.28.0-SNAPSHOT
>
>   > Could not resolve mydep:mydep:1.0.9
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://artifactory.myco.com/artifactory/maven_snapshots-us-east-1-local/mydep/mydep/1.0.9/mydep-1.0.9.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET > 'https://artifactory.myco.com/artifactory/maven_snapshots-us-east-1-local/mydep/mydep/1.0.9/mydep-1.0.9.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict

Is there a way in gradle to tell it to not bother contacting that repo for non-snapshot dependencies? In Maven you can add extra properties in a repository declaration telling Maven whether it allows release dependencies, snapshot dependencies, or both (the default).

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar issues with Gradle 4.x and 5.x, the workaround is to use Gradle 2.x.
By using Gradle 2.x does not stop Gradle search non-snapshot libs from release repository, but at least Gradle can find decency.